# Show elements with row "lugar" value 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a row called `lugar` that have the value 1 or 2.

When I do foreach, i want to filter the elements that have the value 1 in the row lugar and the elements that have the value 2.

`$descuento->lugar` is the variable for the row `lugar`.

Actually, my code is:

```
    <ul id="slider">
      <?php   foreach ( $results['descuentos'] as $descuento ) { 

             $titulo = htmlspecialchars( $descuento->title );
               $title_url = limpiarCaracteresEspeciales($titulo);
               ?>

                    <li>
                        <?php if ( $imagePath = $descuento->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE ) ) { ?>
                  <img  src="<?php echo $imagePath?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $descuento->title )?>" />
                <?php } else {?> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $descuento->title )?>" /> <?php } ?>
                       <div>
                            <strong><span><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $descuento->title )?></span></strong>
                            <p><?php echo $descuento->content ?></p>
                       </div>
                   </li>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>
     </ul>
```

Comment: What is the question? Plus, I see no 'lugar' row in your code.

Comment: Yes because I don't know how to add to filter the foreach. I want to show ONLY the items that in the row "lugar" have the value 1, but now it's appears all, the items with the value 1 and 2.

Comment: when you say 'filter', what do you mean? what do you want to do with the 'lugar' row?

Comment: if($descuento->lugar == 1){ do this };
if($descuento->lugar == 2){ do that };

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer He wants to display rows, only where their "lugar" value is equal to 2.

Comment: I have table discounts with rows title, content, and a row called lugar that have the value 1 or 2. In the foreach I want to show ONLY the items that in the row "lugar" have the VALUE 1.

Comment: @JulioSoares but how I can implement it in the foreach loop?

Comment: @phpeando I'd recommend using the short syntax for PHP embedded in lots of HTML. It makes things much more readable.

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: @DarthGualin and where I need to implement it in the foreach to SELECT only the items that have the row "lugar" value 1? Can you post all the code? Sorry, i'm new in PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you could try this:

```
foreach ( $results['descuentos'] as $descuento )
{

   if( $descuento->lugar == 1)
   {
      $titulo = htmlspecialchars( $descuento->title );
      $title_url = limpiarCaracteresEspeciales($titulo);

      echo '<li>';

      if ( $imagePath = $descuento->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE ) )
      { 
         echo '<img  src="'. $imagePath. '" alt="'. $titulo. '" />';
      } 
      else 
      {
         echo '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/sports/" alt="'. $titulo. '" />';
      }

      echo '<div>'.
            '<strong><span>'. $titulo. '</span></strong>'.
            '<p>'. $descuento->content. '</p>'.
           '</div>'.
          '</li>';
    }
}
```